# Delphi's TreeView - How do I select/highlight node by AbsoluteIndex

Tags: delphi

How would I select/highlight a TreeView node in Delphi if I have its TTreeNode.AbsoluteIndex?

Answer (score 2):

The `AbsoluteIndex` of a node identifies it in the tree's `Items` collection. So if you know the `AbsoluteIndex` you can recover the node like this:

```
Node := Tree.Items[AbsoluteIndex];
```

You can then select this node using the tree's `Select(TTreeNode,TShiftState)` method:

```
Tree.Select(Node);
```